# return message after hook_form_submit without Ajax

Tags: forms

This might seem trivial to many of you, but how can you return a form with a customized message (according to the fields) in a hook_form_submit ? Like :

```
   <?php
/**
 * @file
 * Pages and display.
 */
/**
 * Constantes
 */

/**
 * *************** Formulaire *******************
 */

/**
 * 
 * Implements a standard form.
 */
function MY_MODULE_form($form, $form_state, $arg) {
  $form = array ();
  $form ['#type'] = 'type';
  /**
   * All the form elements
   */

  // soumission du formulaire
  $form ['submit'] = array (
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t ( 'Lancer la simulation' ),
      '#weight' => 10000 
  );

  $form ['simul_message_retour'] = array (
      '#prefix' => '<div id="result-div">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#markup' => isset($form_state ['input']['simul_message_retour']['#markup'])?$form_state ['input']['simul_message_retour']['#markup']:'',
      '#weight' => $form ['submit'] ['#weight'] + 1 
  );
  if (!empty($form_state['response_module'])) { 
    $form['simul_message_retour']['#markup'] = convert_data_to_markup($form_state['response_module']);
  }
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Validation Works
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_numbers = array (
    //Some form fields
  );
  // operations of validation
}

/**
 *
 * @param unknown $form_element          
 * @param unknown $form_state          
 * @return Ambigous <multitype:, unknown>
 */
function MY_MODULE_format_simul_datenaissance($form_element, &$form_state) {
  //checking some of the form construction
}
/**
 * Function of submit
 *
 * @param unknown $form          
 * @param unknown $form_state          
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $form_state['response_module'] = project_call_WS($form, $form_state);
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

/**
 * function processing the call to the WS
 * @param unknown $form          
 * @param unknown $form_state          
 */
 function project_call_WS($form, $form_state){
  // checking if there are no errors
  if (form_get_errors ())
    return '';

  //Operations on the form
  $url = implode ( '/', $url_array );
  $parameters = 'URLTOWEBSERVICE';
  // HERE IS CALLED THE WEBSERVICE(the function call_ws is working well)
  $call = call_ws ($parameters );


  $build = array (
      //ETC
  );
 //Operations on the $builds array
  return $build;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your goal? Form submit and then same form render + messages? If so why not setting messages in `hook_form_validate()`?

Comment: I've tried this too without success. i've added some code in case the problem is elsewhere

Comment: As side note, `MY_MODULE_form()` is NOT an implementation of `hook_form()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form API and message system are not the same thing, even though there are helper functions in the FAPI to produce messages - you don't return a form with a message, you set a message when it's appropriate to do so. That might be when the form is being built, when it's being validated, after it's been submitted, and so on.

Generally speaking, if you're setting a validation error, use `form_set_error()` in a validate callback:

```
function MYMODULE_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (something_wrong_with($form_state['values']['foo'])) {
    form_set_error('foo', 'Run away, bad things happening');
  }
}
```

If you want a confirmation message on form submission, use `drupal_set_message()` in a submit callback:

```
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['foo'] == 'bar') {
    drupal_set_message(t('You chose: %foo', array('%foo' => $form_state['values']['foo'])));
  }
}
```

There's no point returning anything from a form submit callback - it will be ignored. If you want to rebuild the same form again after submission, use:

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

It may or may not be necessary depending on your final goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very instructive. Well, In the hook_form_submit  function i call a webservice that sends back a JSON message that i need to display (after the submit of course).
Since it is not involving `form_set_error()` or `drupal_set_message()`, how can i do that ?

Comment: Do something like this in the submit handler: `$form_state['foo_data'] = func_to_get_web_service_data(); $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;`, then in the form function itself: `if (!empty($form_state['foo_data'])) { $form['foo'] = array('#markup' => convert_data_to_markup($form_state['foo_data']));`

Comment: Sorry but it is still not working. I've put the whole code structure so you could see better the problem

Comment: `$form_state` is passed by reference to the submit handler...

Comment: -_- I just lost half a day because of an &. Sorry for making you loose your time too ! And thank you a lot for your support !

Comment: Heh, we've all been there ;)